# Unable to read image from file ()

Tags: php, laravel

I try to let my users upload their profile image and when i click submit button to save changes will get this error

`NotReadableException in Decoder.php line 20:
Unable to read image from file ().`

this is my update methode in controller:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $this->validate($request, array(
          'first_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
          'last_name' => 'required|string|max:255',
          'gender' => 'required',
          'birthday' => 'required|date_format:d/m/Y|max:25',
          'email' => [
              'required', 'string', 'nullable', 'email', 'max:255',
              Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id),
            ],
          'password' => 'nullable|string|min:6|confirmed',
          'user_image' => 'sometimes|image',
        ));

        $user = User::find($id);

        $user->first_name = $request->input('first_name');
        $user->last_name = $request->input('last_name');
        $user->gender = $request->input('gender');
        $user->birthday = $request->input('birthday');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        if (trim(Input::get('password')) != '') {
          $user->password = Hash::make(trim(Input::get('password')));
        }


        //store user image
        if ($request->hasFile('user_image')) {
          $avatar = $request->file('user_image');
          $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $location = public_path('avatars/' . $filename);
          Image::make($avatar)->resize(200, 200)->save($location);

          $user->image = $filename;
        }

        $user->save();

        Session::flash('success', 'Your information was successfully updated.');

        return redirect()->route('jobseeker.profile', $user->id);
    }
```

This is my blade template image section:

```
<div class="panel-body">
<p>
@if (Auth::user()->image && File::exist(public_path("avatars/" . Auth::user()->image)))
<img src="{{ Auth::user()->image }}" alt="user image" class="img-responsive" >
 @else
<img src="{{ 'https:://www.gravatar.com/avatar/' . md5(strtolower(trim(Auth::user()->email))) . '?s=200&d=wavatar' }}" alt="user image" class="img-responsive" >
   @endif
</p>
<p>
   {{ Form::label('user_image', 'Upload Your Image') }}
   {{ Form::file('user_image') }}
</p>
</div>
```

I'm using Laravel 5.4 and for uploading images I'm using Intervention Image.

Any idea why is that?

Comment: Try $avatar->path() instead of $avatar in your Image make statement

Comment: you mean like this?  `$filename = time() . '.' . $avatar_path()->getClientOriginalExtension();`

Comment: No, in your Image make code, `Image::make($avatar->path( ))`

Comment: @SapneshNaik sorry but i really don't get it! :( would you give me the code please?

Comment: `Image::make($avatar->path())->resize(200, 200)->save($location);`

Comment: Use the one Sabzeeb posted

Comment: @SanzeebAryal now give this error `Image source not readable`

Comment: @robertnicjoo dump if `dd($avatar->path());` returns some real path to temporary file. if no, try also `dd($avatar->getRealPath());`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed my problem with removing Image::make and change my code to:

```
//store user image
        if ($request->hasFile('user_image')) {
          $avatar = $request->file('user_image');
          $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
          $location = public_path('avatars/');
          $request->file('user_image')->move($location, $filename);


          $user->image = $filename;
        }
```

If you have better idea please share.